# How do you add a callback to an angular resource?

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs

I have a view showing a list of items:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
```

The service associated with this is:

```
angular.module('itemService', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Item', function($resource){
        return $resource('/api/v1/item/:itemId', {}, {
            query:   {method:'GET',  params:{itemId : ''},          isArray : true},
            get:     {method:'GET',  params:{itemId : ''},          isArray : false},
            save:    {method:'POST', params:{itemId : ''},          isArray : false},
            update:  {method:'PUT',  params:{itemId : '@_id.$oid'}, isArray : false}
        });
    });
```

finally I use query when the controller is initialied to load the list of items.

```
function ItemCtrl($scope, Item) {

    $scope.items  = Item.query();
    ....
```

On the same page I can create new items and call `save()` to save them to the server. But when I do this I would like to update the view to show the new item instead of reloading the whole list with `query()`. Since the view is the official record I assume that after successfully saving the item I should push it to the end of items. This should be done after `save()` completes so I would like to know how to add/specify a callback to the save function.

EDIT: `save()` returns a copy of the saved item (if successful) so I can ensure that the item was saved successfully on the server.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but can't you just pass the callback when you call Item.save(...)?  Similar to the User.get() example here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

Comment: While this will work in most scenarios, you should be aware pushing the saved record to the list may not be a good practice. It depends on whether the data returning from `query` is identical to that returned by save. In a few scenarios, `query` only returns the most important model properties, while `save` will have all properties; sometimes `save` won't return the full data (like automatic creation_date). So unless you cover all these edge cases, it can make sense to actually call `query` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentaton here:](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)

```
Item.$save(function(item, putResponseHeaders) {
  //item => saved user object
  //putResponseHeaders => $http header getter
});
```